# How to filter a table results when a field value is null

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-data-tools

I'm currently doing reporting using SQL Server Data Tools. Within my report I am using a table, which will display records from my database. I would like to filter my results via

right click on table > tablix properties > filters

The filter I want is if my field (new_description) for example is Null then do not display the record in the table. However I can't seem to get a Null value to work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I had to go onto my Dataset, Open the query designer, and then click on the field that was going to be filtered, and there in the designer you can add a filter which was "IS NULL" and that then would only bring the desired results through

Comment: if you answer your own question you should mark the answer as accepted so that future readers can quickly see that it is compelted.